# Second absolute div with same height as first

Tags: html, css

I have dropdown nav, which is absolute position. I need to to another absolute div as background for this dropdown nav, but I need to do with same height and full width. It is possible to do it? I need to do red background for full screen width, but the red content to keep the content in the same position as it is now.

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

ul li {
 margin-right:30px;
}

.dropdown {
  max-width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
}

.content {
 background:blue;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><span id="span1">1</span></li>
  <li><span id="span2">2</span></li>
  <li><span id="span3">3</span></li>
  <li><span id="span4">4</span></li>
  <li><span id="span5">4</span>
    <div class="">
      <div class="full_background"></div>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>

<p class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus cumque dicta distinctio tempora, eius voluptatum doloremque suscipit numquam, perferendis repellendus animi culpa quo ipsa, eum harum itaque repudiandae, magnam tenetur!</p>
```

Comment: Do you need the blue rectangle the same height as the red one?

Comment: @devsandbox No. I need the content from red to stay in the same position as it is, but the red background was full screen.Possible?

Comment: Do you mean the red background to be full screen, or to be full screen width but the same height as the right hand div? And do you need it to be an actual div, or is it just a background?

Comment: @AHaworth  full screen width but the same height as the right hand div. I just need the background, but to be the same height but full width, but keep the content in actual red to the same position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this not with a separate div but with a pseudo before element. This can be given the same height as the right hand text but be positioned at the left most side of the viewport by translating it by an amount which is the full width of the viewport minus its own width - i.e. it fills the gap. The rest of the red background is already there, on the div with the text in it.

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

ul li {
 margin-right:30px;
}
.dropdown::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: calc(100vw - 100%);
  background: red;
  height: 100%;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}
.dropdown {
  max-width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
}

.content {
 background:blue;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><span id="span1">1</span></li>
  <li><span id="span2">2</span></li>
  <li><span id="span3">3</span></li>
  <li><span id="span4">4</span></li>
  <li><span id="span5">4</span>
    <div class="">
      <div class="full_background"></div>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>

<p class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus cumque dicta distinctio tempora, eius voluptatum doloremque suscipit numquam, perferendis repellendus animi culpa quo ipsa, eum harum itaque repudiandae, magnam tenetur!</p>
```

Comment: Thank you. That's what I'm looking for. You are a god!

Answer (score 0):

Commented each line I added/removed. Basically you need to remove `position: relative` on the `ul` element and add it to the body while stretching out your `.dropdown` element with `top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0` so it can expand to the screens full dimensions.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%; /* push body to full screen height */
}
body {
  position: relative; /* make .dropdown position relative to body */
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  /* position: relative; remove this rule */
}

ul li {
 margin-right:30px;
}

.dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; /*stretch element to nearest positioned parent */
  background: red;
}

.content {
 background:blue;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><span id="span1">1</span></li>
  <li><span id="span2">2</span></li>
  <li><span id="span3">3</span></li>
  <li><span id="span4">4</span></li>
  <li><span id="span5">4</span>
    <div class="">
      <div class="full_background"></div>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>

<p class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus cumque dicta distinctio tempora, eius voluptatum doloremque suscipit numquam, perferendis repellendus animi culpa quo ipsa, eum harum itaque repudiandae, magnam tenetur!</p>
```

If you just want the content of .dropdown to stay in its location while an element stretches the full screen behind it, then i would suggest adding a div outside of the ordered list and absolutely positioning it like below:

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

ul li {
 margin-right:30px;
}

.dropdown {
  max-width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  background: red;
}

.content {
 background:blue;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><span id="span1">1</span></li>
  <li><span id="span2">2</span></li>
  <li><span id="span3">3</span></li>
  <li><span id="span4">4</span></li>
  <li><span id="span5">4</span>
    <div class="">
      <div class="full_background"></div>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>

<p class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus cumque dicta distinctio tempora, eius voluptatum doloremque suscipit numquam, perferendis repellendus animi culpa quo ipsa, eum harum itaque repudiandae, magnam tenetur!</p>

<div class='overlay'></div> <!-- added div that will cover whole page -->
```

Comment: Thank you. But the content in the red window is not in the same position below the content <li> as I have. I just need to make a background, the content has to stay the way I have it. :(

Comment: If you just want a an element to stretch over the whole screen behind the dropdown then i would suggest making a new div outside of the unordered list and using that. I can update my answer to show you an example.

Comment: I understand. But I don't need the whole screen, only the whole WIDTH of the screen. The background must be the same height as the content currently has. If I move it out, I have to set a fixed height and I would need it to be automatically according to the height of the content. :(

Answer (score 0):

So I think I know what you're looking for. You'll need to use js to do this.  For the most part, I used  `width: 99vw;` in `.full_background` to span the full width, then used js to get the height of the dropdown div and apply it to `.full_background`

Here it is:

```js
var dropheight = document.getElementById('redDrop').clientHeight;
document.getElementById("fullbg").style.height = dropheight + "px";
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

ul li {
 margin-right:30px;
}

.dropdown {
  max-width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
}

.content {
 background:blue;
}

.full_background {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  left: 0;
  width: 99vw;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><span id="span1">1</span></li>
  <li><span id="span2">2</span></li>
  <li><span id="span3">3</span></li>
  <li><span id="span4">4</span></li>
  <li><span id="span5">4</span>
    <div class="">
      <div class="full_background" id="fullbg"></div>
      <div class="dropdown" id="redDrop">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>

<p class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus cumque dicta distinctio tempora, eius voluptatum doloremque suscipit numquam, perferendis repellendus animi culpa quo ipsa, eum harum itaque repudiandae, magnam tenetur!</p>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!